# How to calculate the shadow price in Gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I want to analyze whether the boundary should increase or reduce in Constraints in a programming problem:
The following is simplified problem. `V[(i,t)]`is decision variable and `S[i]` is input. I want to know if the obj increases or reduces when increasing one unit of S[i]`. 
I know may the shadow price and marginal cost are for decision variable not inputs. In Gurobi, Dual value (also known as the shadow price) can use the Pi function.

```
for t in range(T):
    for i in range(I):
        m.addConstr(V[(i,t)] <= Lambda*S[i])
        m.addConstr(other constrints without S[i])
obj =cf*quicksum(V[(i,0)] for i in range(I))+ cs*quicksum(S[i]for i in range(I))+...
m.setObjective(obj, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
m.optimize()
```

Comment: Why not use the Pi constraint attribute?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to get the shadow price:(Python + Gurobi):

```
shadow_price = model.getAttr('Pi', model.getConstrs())
```

or

```
shadow_price = model.getAttr(GRB.Attr.Pi)
```

It returns the shadow prices of all constraints in sequence into an array.

Comment: How can I find the reduced cost? Is there a function for that?