# Gurobi shadow price of a variable without generating separate constraint

Tags: c++, optimization, gurobi

Gurobi 9.0.0 // C++

I am trying to get the shadow price of variables without explicitly generating a constraint for them.

I am generating variables the following way:

```
GRBModel* milp_model
milp_model->addVar(lb, up, type, 0, name)
```

Now I would like to get the shadow price (dual) for these variables.

I found this [article](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360050740452-Querying-the-dual-variables-associated-to-variable-bounds) which says that for "a linear program with lower and upper bounds on a variable, i.e., l ≤ x ≤ u" [...] "Gurobi gives access to the reduced cost of x, which corresponds to sl+su".

To get the **shadow price of a constraint** one would use the GRB functions according to the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49126492/how-to-calculate-the-shadow-price-in-gurobi) (python but same idea) using the Pi constraint attribute.

What would be the GRB function that returns the previously mentioned reduced cost of x / **shadow price of a variable**?

I tried `gurobi_var.get(GRB_DoubleAttr_Pi)` which works for `gurobi_constr.get(GRB_DoubleAttr_Pi)`

but it returns: `Not right attribute. Error code = 10003`

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are referring to the reduced costs of the variables. You can get them via the variable attribute `RC` as explained [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/rc.html). And then you need to figure out whether these dual values are corresponding to the upper or lower bound as discussed [here](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Gurobi.jl/issues/250).